# What does the MONITOR privilege on database level in Snowflake DB?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I can grant MONITOR privilege to my role with:

```
GRANT MONITOR ON DATABASE DB1 TO ROLE MYROLE;
```

I checked [Snowflake docs > Managing Security In Snowflake > Access Control in Snowflake > Access Control Privileges](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/security-access-control-privileges.html#all-privileges-alphabetical) and the explanation is very sparse:

> MONITOR  Resource Monitor, Warehouse, Database, Schema, Task Grans ability to see details within an object (e.g. queries and usage within a warehouse)

So what actions can I do when I have MONITOR what I could not do without it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MONITOR` on database level will allow you to perform at least [`DESCRIBE DATABASE`](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/desc.html)

```
DESCRIBE DATABASE DB1;
```

I don't know if there are other commands enabled by `MONITOR`.